# Flags defined in different functions with sync giving error

Tags: go, multiprocessing, synchronization, ping, flags

I want to run two functions simultaneously with some flags, but the below golang script is working if they are't calling the flags `go run ping.go` ie., they will use default values.

ping.go file below

```
    package main

import (
    //   "io/ioutil"
    //   "log"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func pingone() {
    websiteone := flag.String("websiteone", "adminone", "Zdefault website")

    flag.Parse()
    // using/printing flags to avoid error

    fmt.Println("website:", *websiteone)

    eurl := "https://thesiteone.com/"
    happ := "/subpage"

    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(eurl + *websiteone + happ)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(resp)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}

func pingtwo() {
    websitetwo := flag.String("websitetwo", "admintwo", "Zdefault website")

    flag.Parse()
    // using/printing flags to avoid error

    fmt.Println("website:", *websitetwo)

    eurltwo := "https://thesitetwo.com/"
    happtwo := "/subpage"

    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(eurltwo + *websitetwo + happtwo)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(resp)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    fmt.Printf("Both pingone and pingtwo started\n")

    wg.Add(2)
    go pingone()
    go pingtwo()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("both pingone and pingtwo have finished\n")

}
```

but if we calls these both flags simultaneously
`go run ping.go --websitetwo='secondsuburl' --websiteone='firstsuburl'`
results they get wrecked

** About the above code **

The script will run two functions both are pinging different website simultaneously using sync.

Don't get confused, here the url is splitted into three parts/string : the second part is where the flag defined.

Output below

```
root@localhost:~# go run ping.go --websiteone=admin1 --websitetwo=admin2
Both pingone and pingtwo started
flag provided but not defined: -websiteone
Usage of /tmp/go-build010683275/b001/exe/ping:
  -websiteone string
        Zdefault website (default "adminone")
website: admin1
  -websitetwo string
        Zdefault website (default "admintwo")
exit status 2
```

Comment: I think you should only be calling flag.Parse once after defining both of your flags. You're calling it twice.

Comment: You forget to pass the waitgroup to each function to call Done when it finishes. This code will hang forever

Comment: I think you should call the options with one dash instead two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put the flag arg statements separately, place them into a single func, call the `flag.Parse()` once, then pass the arguments into both `pingone()` and `pingtwo()`.

I adjusted your code below, it should fix your issue

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func pingone(websiteone *string) {
    fmt.Println("website:", *websiteone)

    eurl := "https://thesiteone.com/"
    happ := "/subpage"

    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(eurl + *websiteone + happ)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(resp)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}

func pingtwo(websitetwo *string) {
    fmt.Println("website:", *websitetwo)

    eurltwo := "https://thesitetwo.com/"
    happtwo := "/subpage"

    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(eurltwo + *websitetwo + happtwo)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(resp)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    websiteone := flag.String("websiteone", "adminone", "Zdefault website")
    websitetwo := flag.String("websitetwo", "admintwo", "Zdefault website")

    flag.Parse()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    fmt.Printf("Both pingone and pingtwo started\n")

    wg.Add(2)
    go pingone(websiteone)
    go pingtwo(websitetwo)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("both pingone and pingtwo have finished\n")
}
```

Comment: You forget to ALSO pass the waitgroup to each function to call Done when it finishes. This code will hang forever

Comment: even with/without calling the `.Done()`, the code will run forever. the `for` loop within each goroutine is infinite loop. I don't know why the code designed that way. but my answer here only focus on the flag parsing part

Comment: Sure, i did no see it was on the original code too

Comment: Actually the point of my question is running two functions with multiple flags. Thanks that worked. @novalagung.               
and here i just recreated a similar example or issue that i faced in my another script (that script is too long with many functions , so its hard to explain here )